# How to open a fragment from another fragment using a button in android

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to get from one fragment to another using a button I have added an onClickListener to the button but when I click the button the app crashes and I get the error
No view found for id 0x7f08006f (com.example.streetsafe:id/container) for fragment ReportFragment{afb1ae2} (1513262d-c043-45b9-a229-646e64d334db) id=0x7f08006f}.

MainActivity

```java
    package com.example.streetsafe;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import com.example.streetsafe.ui.report.ReportFragment;
    import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import androidx.navigation.NavController;
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
    import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
    import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
            // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
            AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                    R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_report)
                    .build();
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    
    
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
    
        }
    
    }
```

HomeFragment

```java
    package com.example.streetsafe.ui.home;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
    
    import com.example.streetsafe.R;
    import com.example.streetsafe.ui.report.ReportFragment;
    
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    
        private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    
    
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            homeViewModel =
                    new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    
            Button btn1=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.button_report);
    
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FragmentTransaction fr=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fr.replace(R.id.container,new ReportFragment());
                    fr.commit();
                }
            });
    
    
            //retrieves text from home view file
            final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
            homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                    textView.setText(s);
                }
            });
            final TextView textView1 = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home2);
            homeViewModel.getText1().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                    textView1.setText(s);
                }
            });
    
            return root;
    
    
    
    
        }
    
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#12A3CF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp">
    
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/title_streetsafe"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="45dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">
    
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_report"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_title_report"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.828"
            app:backgroundTint="#12A3CF"/>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The [fragment] tag's description asks to not use the tag.

Answer (score 0):

seems like error caused by this line:

```
fr.replace(R.id.container,new ReportFragment());
```

If I remember it right, you can pass `container` argument here instead of id - `R.id.container`. Seems like android can't find any views in fragment's `ReportFragment` layout, and it's correct behavior for android, cause `R.id.containter` - is id for ConstraintLayout in `activity_main.xml` (MainActivity)

Comment: what should I done instead how should I change that line of code

Comment: @user2525009 try this - `fr.replace(container, new ReportFragment());`

Comment: tried it seems to give an error: incompatible types: ViewGroup cannot be converted to int fr.replace(container,new ReportFragment());